# How can i get the id of the max record?

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate

Here is a situation where i need to get the last date of apppointment for a contact and i also need the id of the last appointment date.

All appointments are stored in custom object and has a lookup to contact.

```
  SELECT Max(startDate__c ) FROM appointments Group by contact__c
```

IS there a way to get id of the appointment for which the max(startDate__c) is returned?
I want to have for each contact which is the latest appointment date and the id of the latest appointment.

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT Contact__c ContactId, MAX(StartDate__c) StartDate FROM Appointments__c GROUP BY Contact__c` would do this, but the subquery method uses fewer rows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not with just a subquery?

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id, StartDate__c FROM Appointments__r ORDER BY StartDate__c DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM Contact
```

Keep it simple, aggregate functions "waste" query rows (for example [COUNT() will return only 1 row but will use up N rows from the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984349/limitexception-too-many-query-rows-50001-from-with-count-aggregate-function))

Comment: just deviating a bit, is there a way other than using aggregate function to get count. ?

Comment: Non-row wasting you mean (so no `[SELECT...].size()` and such stuff)? I'm not aware of any Apex-y tricks. If you can plan ahead - rollup summary field (can be with conditional logic), maybe have a look at Analytic Snapshots (basically you schedule feeding of some reports output into a helper object and later you can rely on this helper object with "flattened" data in Apex or other reports). And last but not least - Setup -> Storage Usage ;)

Comment: if start_date__c can be null then you need to use: `SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id, StartDate__c FROM Appointments__r WHERE start_date__c != null ORDER BY StartDate__c DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM Contact`  otherwise the Appointments with null start_date__c will be returned first as the 'highest' value

Comment: @crop1645 fair point, that's one way although SF doesn't always like filtering out nulls (non-selective query...). Another option would be to ORDER BY StartDate__c NULLS LAST. No idea which one would be better performance-wise.

Answer (score -2):

first group by startdate and then you got left is 1 record from that run again max(id) that will return id

```
SELECT Max(startDate__c ), max(id) 
FROM appointments 
Group by contact__c
```

Comment: no, it's not correct this will get the Max startDate__c and MAX of ID from different records with the same contact__c