# How to query for the most recent cases in a list of contacts but only return one per contact?

Tags: apex, soql

I am struggling to get a list containing the most recent case from a list of contacts.

So I would like the query to return only one case(the most recent) per contact.

How can I change the query below to get only one case per contact?

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Case 
WHERE Origin='Chat' 
AND ContactId IN :contactIds 
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the id of the max record?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-the-max-record)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Cases WHERE Origin='Chat' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIds
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error "Didn't understand relationship 'Case' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Comment: @PepeFloyd I'm sorry. I forgot the "s". It should be "FROM Cases". I've updated this answer.

Comment: Awesome! that did it!