# Get Record Id of Max(Date) record from Aggregate Result SOQL query (most recent campaign membership by campaign enddate)

Tags: apex, soql, campaign-member, aggregateresult

First time using aggregate functions in SOQL in Apex, and looking for a little bit of help.

I'm trying to pull the "last" campaign membership off a contact in apex so that I can update their status, but last as in Max(Campaign.EndDate) not Max(CreatedDate) from CampaignMember.

My goal is to get a set of campaign memberships that are of the most recent "xyz" campaign, so my query looks like:

```
List <AggregateResult> mostRecentCMs = [SELECT ContactId, MAX(Id) id, MAX(Campaign.EndDate) FROM CampaignMember
  WHERE ContactId = :contactList AND Campaign.Type = 'XYZ' AND Status = 'Responded' GROUP BY ContactId];
```

but I don't know 1. if that query is right and 2. how to get that list into a set of CampaignMember Ids. My best guess at the latter based off [Jeff Douglas' post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/12/using-aggregateresult-in-salesforce-com-soql/) is as follows, but I don't really understand the cmSet.add((ID)results.get('id')) part. What I'm particularly concerned with is that the Max(Id) is not the same thing as the Id of the CampaignMember record with the Max(Campaign.EndDate).

```
for(AggregateResult ar : mostrecentCMs){
  System.debug(ar.get('ContactId') + '-' + ar.get('id'));
}

for (AggregateResult results : mostrecentCMs){
  mqlsToSAL.add((ID)results.get('id'))
}
for(CampaignMember sal : mostRecentCMs){
  sal.Status = 'SAL';
  toUpdate.add(sal);
}
```

I got worried based off [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-the-max-record) that I should actually be using a subquery instead of an aggregate function, but I don't think that make sense when Campaign isn't a child of CampaignMember.

Can anyone help get me past this roadblock and/or course correct me?

Edit:
Based off Adrian's idea, maybe this should work off the Campaign. Does the below look correct?

```
List <Campaign> c = [SELECT Id, EndDate,
    (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMembers WHERE Status = 'Responded')
FROM Campaign WHERE Type = 'XYZ' AND Id IN
    (SELECT CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE ContactId = :contactList)
ORDER BY EndDate desc limit 1];

Set <CampaignMember> mostRecentCMs = new Set <CampaignMember>;
mostRecentCMs.add(c.CampaignMembers);

Set <Id> cmsToUpdate = new Set <Id>;
for (CampaignMember cm : mostRecentCMs){
    cmsToUpdate.add(cm.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing this as two queries, one off the campaign earlier in the trigger:

```
  List <Campaign> activeCampaign = [
  SELECT Id, Name, Type, StartDate, EndDate FROM Campaign
  WHERE Type = 'xyz' ORDER BY EndDate desc
  LIMIT 1];
```

and then using that query's results in a bind variable later:

```
  List <CampaignMember> mostRecentCMs = [SELECT Id, CampaignId, ContactId, Status FROM CampaignMember
  WHERE ContactId = :contactList AND CampaignId = :activeCampaign[0].Id];
```

Works well enough. I bet there's still some way to consolidate this into one query, but this has been working for us in the meantime!

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have an easier time querying `Campaign` directly here:

```
SELECT EndDate,
    (
        SELECT ContactId FROM CampaignMembers
        WHERE Status = 'Responded'
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
    )
FROM Campaign WHERE Type = 'XYZ' AND Id IN (
    SELECT CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Status = 'Responded'
)
```

There are a few things going on here:

- You can use a **[`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join)** to get the child `CampaignMember` records within the same query.

  - These query rows count against your per transaction limit.
  - The query itself counts against a different limit than parent queries, and is somewhat misleadingly retrieved using `Limits.getAggregateQueries()`
- You can use a **[`Left Inner Join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join)** to check that there actually are matching child records.

  - These query rows do *not* count against your limits consumption.
  - This sub-query does not count against limit consumption either.

Comment: Hi Adrian, you might be right but your above example doesn't work for what I need, so I just want to make sure changing it doesn't change its eligibility as an answer.

1. I need the Id of the CampaignMembers, not the ContactId (this is a trigger on Contacts, so I have a set of Contact Ids as the CampaignMember where clause as a bind variable).
2 The date filter needs to be on the Campaign, not the CampaignMember (Order by Campaign EndDate desc Limit 1, to allow for late adds on campaigns).
3. I need to add the CampaignMember Ids to a set.

Do you think my edits to question would work?

Comment: Ah poop I just wrote up the edits but I forgot - I can't do limit 1 on the campaign because that will only return 1 campaign, when there could be multiple here at play.